# Writing a Stored Function in Java (JDBC)

Tags: java, sql, hive, callable-statement

In attempting to test the callable procedure in java, I have ran across an error when attempting to call a stored procedure that reports the sign of a given input parameter (int)

```
    CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{CALL sign(?,"+testVal+")}");
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
```

The stacktrace reads:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera][JDBC](11420) Error, parameter metadata not populated.
at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.jdbc.common.SCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.jdbc.common4.C4SCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.jdbc.jdbc41.S41CallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.jdbc.jdbc41.JDBC41ObjectFactory.createCallableStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.hive.jdbc41.HiveJDBC41ObjectFactory.createCallableStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
at TestMethods.callableStatement(TestMethods.java:263)
at HiveJdbcGeneralTest.testTableCreation(HiveJdbcGeneralTest.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at
```

Comment: One error is the semicolon after  total(origin STRING)

Comment: Fixed! Same error still; however.

Comment: reading the error message and the refernce i think there is somthing expected like `CREATE FUNCTION [db_name.]function_name AS class_name
  [USING JAR|FILE|ARCHIVE 'file_uri' [, JAR|FILE|ARCHIVE 'file_uri'] ];`

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused as to why that would be necessary, given that this is a (database) stored procedure performing a fairly simple function.

Comment: Unless the return refers to a variable name while the as refers to the return type of the variable

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I think you are trying to write stored procedure for Hive.
In this case as you can see HPL/SQL != PL/SQL.
The right syntax of a stored procedure can be found [here](http://www.hplsql.org/udf-sproc).

Comment: Please read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/182862) and [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/182862)

Comment: I tried editing to conform with the guide, but don't understand the usage of "AS" after declaring the name of the function.